# Login screen characters all question marks, login info isn't working

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, screen, login-screen

I just reinstalled high Sierra after my Mac wouldn't restart. The moment it loads up I am presented with this screen. My login credentials don't work. Can someone explain to me what this screen is and what I'm supposed to input?
[image]

Comment: reinstall again

Comment: Didn't work, same thing

Comment: Boot to recovery. Is all the text question marks? How did you reinstall macOS? Just want to make sure we're doing everything correctly.  Also try Internet recovery.

Comment: Was it a clean install (as in, the drive was wiped completely and OS installed from a flash drive etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a font corruption issue. If you can boot into recovery mode and access Terminal you might be able to solve the problem by restoring the default system fonts.

First, to boot to recovery mode: Reboot your machine holding CMD + R until you see the Apple logo.

When you see the "Utilities" screen, choose "Utilities" from the menu, and then Terminal

Paste the following into Terminal:

fontrestore default

Press RETURN.

If this doesn’t fix the problem then paste the following after the prompt:

sudo atsutil databases -remove

Press RETURN.

Close terminal and restart normally.

Comment: Tried that, terminal didn't recognize either commands

Comment: Nevermind it worked

Comment: @aafaa23 how did you solve the unrecognised command issue?